# Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

When I try to debug my program, this Exception is being thrown in a call to `glGenBuffers`. I'm  using OpenGL and SDL. Here is my code:

It consists of two classes:
m and sprite

s is var of sprite class

class  m  is like this:

```
void run()
{
    init();
    s.init(-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    loop();
}


void  init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("mine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1024, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (window == nullptr) {

        fatalerror("cant create (open) window");
    }

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (context == nullptr) {

        fatalerror("context cant be created ");


    }
    GLenum cerror = glewInit();
    if (cerror != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fatalerror("cant init glew:(");
    }
    std::cout << "ok";


    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


}

void looploop()
{
    while (state != gamestate::exit)
    {

        input();
        draw();
    }

}
void M::input()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&events)) {

        switch (events.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            state = gamestate::exit;
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            std::cout << events.motion.x << ',' << events.motion.y << "\n";
            break;
        }



    }

}

void draw()
{
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    s.draw();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

}
```

class sprite:

```
void init(float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _w = w;
    _h = h;

    if (vboid == 0) {


        glGenBuffers(1, &vboid);
    }

    float vertexdata[12];
    //first triangle
    vertexdata[0] = x + w;
    vertexdata[1] = y + w;
    vertexdata[2] = x;
    vertexdata[3] = y + h;
    vertexdata[4] = x;
    vertexdata[5] = y;
    //second triangle
    vertexdata[6] = x;
    vertexdata[7] = y ;
    vertexdata[8] = x+h;
    vertexdata[9] =  y;
    vertexdata[10] = x+w;
    vertexdata[11] = y+h;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboid);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertexdata),vertexdata,GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        ;

}


void draw()
{


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboid);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribLPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboid);

}
```

Comment: Where is `vboid` defined? If that were either `null` or part of an object that was deleted, it could cause this problem.

Comment: 0x00000000 is a NULL pointer; from what you say, the glGenBuffers function pointer seems to not be set. What hardware have you?

Comment: thanks for answer  vboid equals to zero  in the constructor maybe  its the hardware

Comment: my display adapter is Intel(R) G41 Express Chipest(Microsoft Corporation-WDDM1.1)

Comment: i have 2GB ram ,my processor is Intel pentium(R) pentium(R)4 CPU 3.20GHZ,my operation system is windows 7  32bit

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, you're on ms windows?

You need to "wrangle the OpenGL extension" using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).
Personally, I use OpenGL Core Profile, and use [GL3W](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) to do this for me on the windows platform.

Without doing glewInit() or gl3wInit() first, your extension function pointers are all nil, hence the crash.

On all other platforms (Linux, MacOS, etc) this is not necessary. Root cause for this is Microsoft's Installable Client Driver model.

Comment: I used glewinit but it didn.t solve the problem

Comment: could this  Exception thrown due to  the  oldness  of my hardware or  not